# I can't get a photo from local in my Android Studio project. (GlideException: Failed to load resource)

Tags: android, node.js, kotlin, android-glide, android-image

I'm using glide in my android project. And images doesn't loading. I get "class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource" error. And a photo url from the internet it is works.

```
inner class PetViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val nameText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.petNameTextView)
        private val petImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.petImageView)
        
        fun bind(pet: Pet) {
            nameText.text = pet.Name
            Glide.with(itemView.context)
                .load("/Users/macbookair/Desktop/evcil_hayvan_app/uploads/pet_29022024004317.jpg")
                .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                    override fun onLoadFailed(
                        e: GlideException?,
                        model: Any?,
                        target: Target<Drawable>?,
                        isFirstResource: Boolean
                    ): Boolean {
                        Log.e("Glide", "Image loading failed", e)
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Drawable?,
                        model: Any?,
                        target: Target<Drawable>?,
                        dataSource: DataSource?,
                        isFirstResource: Boolean
                    ): Boolean {
                        //başarılı yükleme durumunda burası çalışacak
                        return false
                    }
                })
                .into(petImage)
        }
    }
```

Log as Follows:

```
Image loading failed
                                                                                                    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
                                                                                                    There were 3 causes:
                                                                                                    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/Users/macbookair/Desktop/evcil_hayvan_app/uploads/pet_29022024004317.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
                                                                                                    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
                                                                                                    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
                                                                                                     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
                                                                                                      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, LOCAL
                                                                                                    There was 1 cause:
                                                                                                    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/Users/macbookair/Desktop/evcil_hayvan_app/uploads/pet_29022024004317.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
                                                                                                     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
                                                                                                        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
```

I can't get a photo from local. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`/Users/macbookair/Desktop/evcil_hayvan_app/uploads/pet_29022024004317.jpg` would appear to be a filesystem path for a macOS machine.

Your code is for an Android app. macOS does not run Android apps. Android does not use macOS filesystem paths.

Your `load()` call needs to reference something that the Android app can reach. It cannot reach into your macOS machine via a filesystem path. So, perhaps instead upload your image to a Web server and use an `https://` URL with `load()`.